# Getting a plugin path using Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

How to get a plugin path using Python?  I tried `QgsApplication.pluginPath()`

I got `u'/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../PlugIns/qgis'`.

But I actually store the plugin in `~/.qgis2/python/plugins/myplugin`.

Comment: You want the path to your own plugin?

Comment: Yes, I want the path to my own plugin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use this in my plugins:

```
def resolve(name, basepath=None):
    if not basepath:
      basepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(basepath, name)
```

This is handy if you want a file relative to your plugin e.g

- plugin.py
- icon.png

`resolve('icon.png')` will return the full path to icon.png.

Put this function inside a top level file for you plugin.