# Insert image in QGIS Plugin using qt creator

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt

I'm building qgis plugin and i use Qt creator to creat a form. I want insert a image and i use a label to do this. In the field pixmap i choose a file image.png.
I save and in QGIS i reload a plugin and the image don't appear. I edit the file xxxx.ui and i see this

```
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap>image.png</pixmap>
   </property>
```

but if i do that

```
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap>C:\Users\...\.qgis2\python\plugins\...\image.png</pixmap>
   </property>
```

the image appear.But if i use in another PC the image disappear again because the Path is different.
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 6):

It's a while ago I did this this the last time but as far as I remember you can use a resource-file http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc , add your image there,  choose the image from this resource in qt-designer and compile the resources.

Edit1: Screenshot added: Assign Image from ressources, not from file:

[image]

---

**Edit2:**
I just gave it a try again and this workflow was successful:

1. put your image into your plugin-folder and add it to your ressources file:
   [image]
2. compile your resources file:

   pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
3. open the ui-file in QT-Designer and edit resources --> open resource file
   [image]
4. assign logo from resources to label, not from file!

[image]

So your code points to your resource file:

```
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap>:/plugins/stackexchange/logo.png</pixmap>
   </property>
```

If you are using plugin-builder you should use the latest version. Otherwise an error could occur ("ImportError: No module named resources_rc")
( https://github.com/g-sherman/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/issues/34 ) 
that would have to be fixed manually by changing

```
 <resources>
  <include location="resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
```

back to

```
  <resources/>
```

(solution found here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155599/45041).

If you use the newest plugin-builder you won't have to compile the ui again, otherwise you will have to do this step, too.

There you are:

[image]

PS: I'm not sure if this is the most 'elegant' way to get the image into your plugin, as I'm not woking that much with python/PyQt **yet** ;)

Answer (score 2):

If it does not work from within the `*.ui` you can still assign the pixmap from your corresponding `*.py` file:

```py
self.label1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/plugins/PluginName/image.png"))
```

If the image is not found you can try the [resolve function by Nathan W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130031/8673) to find the image in the plugin structure.

```py
img_path = resolve('image.png')
self.label1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(logo_path))
```